# Returning true or false without me telling it to... python 3

Tags: python, testing, if-statement, boolean, statements

I'm trying to figure this out. I want to enter a students grade into my program. The grade must be between 0 and 100.

I wrote the code that it returns False if grade is less than 0 or greater and 100, and told it to return True if the grade is less than 100 and greater than 0.

But how do I make my program return True and False, without telling it...return True, return False etc....

Cause I know when you type 2 == 2. It returns True without you telling it to.

```
grd=input("What is the grade?") 
if (grd<0) or (grd>100): 
    return False
else:
    return True
```

and

```
grd=int(input("Enter the grade please"))
while((0<=grd) and (grd<=100))!=True:
         print("The grade is invalid. Please try again:")
         grd=int(input("Grade please: "))
print("The grade is valid")
```

Comment: Without any code it's hard to tell, but the way you did it seems like it should work. A shorter way to do it would be `return 0 <= grade <= 100`

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your code should work.

Comment: Aren't you missing `||` in your `if` statement?

Comment: fixed* and I'm just trying to return true or false, without saying return True and return False.

Answer (score 1):

```
return 0 <= grade <= 100
```

Comment: grade = input("Enter a grade for the student: ")
return 0 <= grade <= 100 (This doesn't work, why?)

Comment: @user3376651, what do you mean "doesn't work"? Syntax error? Runtime exception? Wrong return value?

Comment: Your computer was blown up, maybe?

Comment: I got it to work. It needs to be inside a function i figured out.